# IMU sensor plugin in drcsim

Tags: gazebo-plugin, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi all,

where does the .cpp code exist for this imu plugin. This is from

```
drcsim / ros / atlas_description / urdf / atlas.gazebo
```

```
  
    
    
    
      1
      1000.0
      
        
          gaussian
          
          
            0.0
            2e-4
            0.0000075
            0.0000008
          
          
            0.0
            1.7e-2
            0.1
            0.001
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3118/imu-sensor-plugin-in-drcsim/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In Gazebo's [gazebo/sensors/ImuSensor.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/bc4aa2b5650c709730578275ca43d05a5005bbfe/gazebo/sensors/ImuSensor.cc?at=default)

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-06-05**:
@ThomasK Thanks. In my standalone installation (1.7.1) I could find ImuSensor.hh at /usr/include/gazebo-1.7/gazebo/sensors/ImuSensor.hh but ImuSensor.cc or a .so file is nowhere to be found. I am wondering why?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-06-05**:
Lack of .cc file is expected, debian packages are not including source files. Headers files are needed for developing against gazebo and binary code for Imu Sensor is part libgazebo_sensors.so. (try to run nm -D libgazebo_sensors.so | grep Imu). I would recommended download source code from bitbucket if you plan on looking at code.

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-06-05**:
@Jose Luis Rivero Thanks!